# com_error at /translator/translator_upload/ (-2147221008, 'CoInitialize has not been called.', None, None)

Tags: python, django, pdf, ms-word, pywin32

I am new to web development and trying to create a language translation app in Django that translates uploaded documents. It relies on a series of interconversions between pdf and docx. When my code ouputs the downloaded translated document I sometimes get a `com_error at /translator/translator_upload/ (-2147221008, 'CoInitialize has not been called.', None, None)`. Here is the full error message:

```
Exception Location: C:\Users\John\tutorial-env\Lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py, line 86, in _GetGoodDispatch
Raised during:  translator_upload.views.translateFile
Python Executable:  C:\Users\John\tutorial-env\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.11.4
Python Path:    
['C:\\djangoProjects\\mysite',
 'C:\\Users\\John\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\python311.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\John\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\John\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib',
 'C:\\Users\\John\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311',
 'C:\\Users\\John\\tutorial-env',
 'C:\\Users\\John\\tutorial-env\\Lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\John\\tutorial-env\\Lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 'C:\\Users\\John\\tutorial-env\\Lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\John\\tutorial-env\\Lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']
```

Here is my code:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect
from .models import TranslatedDocument
from .forms import UploadFileForm
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
import docx
from pdf2docx import parse
from docx2pdf import convert
import time #remove




# Create your views here.

@csrf_protect
def translateFile(request) :
    file = ''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            uploaded_file = request.FILES['file']
            fs = FileSystemStorage()
            filename = fs.save(uploaded_file.name, uploaded_file)
            uploaded_file_path = fs.path(filename)
            
            file = (converter(uploaded_file_path))
        response = HttpResponse(file, content_type='application/pdf')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="' + filename + '"'
        return response
    
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render(request, 'translator_upload/upload.html', {'form': form})    


def reConverter(inputDocxPath):
    return convert(inputDocxPath)

def translateDocx(aDocx, stringOfDocPath):
    docx_file = stringOfDocPath
    myDoc = docx.Document(docx_file)

    #translation logic



    myDoc.save(stringOfDocPath)
    return reConverter(stringOfDocPath)


    
#stringOfDocPath is used as convert() requires file path, not file object(myDoc)

def converter(inputPdfPath):
    # convert pdf to docx
    
    pdf_file = inputPdfPath
    docx_file = inputPdfPath + '.docx'


    parse(pdf_file, docx_file) #,  start=0, end=3)
    myDoc = docx.Document(docx_file)
    return translateDocx(myDoc, docx_file)
```

I tried adding

```
pythoncom.CoInitialize()
# Use the COM object here
pythoncom.CoUninitialize()
```

But that did not work. Note that I only get this error sometimes and never after retrying(so not twice in a row).

Comment: Try adding `pythoncom.CoInitialize()` at the top of *translateFile*.

Comment: @CristiFati Hi, it is still producing the same error.